# Use objc_setAssociatedObject to set border color does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why using objc_setAssociatedObject to set the border color is not working?

Will upvote if you also address this one (assuming you can make objc_setAssociatedObject to work):  What are the advantages of using objc_setAssociatedObject in this sample?

Edit:  I am not looking for how to set a border color.  But I saw the use of objc_setAssociatedObject from a third party library for this purpose,  and could not try it on my test sample.

Edit2: With the comments from @Leo, I finally figured out what was my misconception of that usage.  It actually was adding a property to the object.  To demo:

Adding this method:

```
-(UIColor *)borderColor
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(label1, kBorderColorKey);
}
```

And this line will work:

```
label1.layer.borderColor = [[self borderColor] CGColor];


static char * kBorderColorKey = "border color key";
-(void)setColorButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"setColorButton");

    //This line does not work
    objc_setAssociatedObject(label1, kBorderColorKey, [UIColor redColor], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    //This line works
    label1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
}
```

Comment: Why should this ever work?

Comment: @leo:  The code came from this library: https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit inside the UIView+Border.m

Comment: If you know why it should not work, then state the reasons so.  That was the question.  Why wait time and down vote?

Comment: Well, I personally did not downvote your question. The thing you want to achieve and the code you posted are just downright unrelated, so I was curious what gave you the impression they are...

Comment: What the mentioned library does is: it adds a `borderColor` property to every `UIView` - which allows to store an NSColor associated with each view instance. But this has nothing to do with the actual drawing of the border, which happens here https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/blob/master/MBCalendarKit/CalendarKit/Categories/UIKit/UIView/UIView%2BBorder.m#L14

Comment: @Leo:  If you put your last comment in the answer, I will select it as the answer and earned the upvote as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have discovered is a widely used mechanism to add properties to third-party classes through categories. `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` allow to store arbitrary objects attached to other objects. So basically you define a getter and a setter in your category, but instead of setting (and getting) an instance variable, these getters and setters dispatch to the mentioned Objective C runtime functions.

However, this is in no way related to the drawing of a border. This code still has to be executed explicityly, e.g. by calling it from within the setter of your associated object.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the associated object for an arbitrary key will not have specific behaviour. If instead you had used:

```
static char * kBorderColorKey = "layer.borderColor";
```

I would be more willing to believe that it might work. It won't, but it at least looks like it might. Using `"border color key"` is roughly the same as using `"do magic because I want you to"` to accomplish the same result.

Because the layer's `borderColor` is not assigned as an associated object when it is created, you won't be able to change its value in this way. In order to properly access it via KVO, you could consider doing this:

```
[label1 setValue:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor] forKey:@"layer.borderColor"];
```

However, I don't see why you don't just use the line that you already have that works:

```
label1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```